# Свернуть приложение по кнопке back

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте. Проблема такая: не могу никак придумать код в метод

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed ()
{
}
```

Нужно свернуть приложение, а то по нажатии кнопки назад приложение закрывается :(

Answer (score 2):

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startMain);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно что имеется ввиду под свернуть... Сворачивание это видимо закрытие активити, но при этом надо иметь ввиду, что приложение не обязательно убивается. Решение о закрытии приложения принимает ось самостоятельно с учетом наличия ресурсов, памяти и проч. Закрытие текущего активити делается через `Activity.finish()`

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed () 
{ 
   this.finish();
}
```

**Update** Если нужно восстановить состояние до нажатия BACK то надо при нажатии BACK сохранить значения элементов активити и далее при onCreate() восстановить их значения. Подробно это [разжевано здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

Comment: имею ввиду как раз не закрытие активити, а так, что бы при нажатие на иконку программы, снова восстановить то состояние, из которого была нажата кнопка назад. сейчас если нажимаю на нее, закрывается активити и приложение, в общем закрывается полностью все

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить событие KEYCODE_BACK на KEYCODE_HOME

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return super.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME, event);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**Update**: а ну правильно. в документации к KEYCODE_HOME написано: *This key is handled by the framework and is never delivered to applications.*
Значит никак вы не сможете сэмулировать сворачивание

Comment: не срабатывает. метод ловится, но ничего не происходит, ни выход, ни сворачивание, хотя по логике код правильный

Comment: Получилось так:
 
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
         moveTaskToBack(true);
         return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }